# Angular2/4: Alerts and notifications from the server

Tags: angular, signalr, angular2-services, signalr-hub

I am creating a new Angular 2/4 application. On the home page, I need to show any urgent/emergency messages that I have received from the server. I am wondering what would be the best choice in this case. I looked in to some of the libraries but of no use. will signalr help in this case? or google material ?

Comment: the exact behavior you want is unclear. You want notifications to open up as the user loads the homepage?

Comment: you can use server sent events.

Comment: @BeetleJuice Not as the user loads. The notifications can come at any time   when I am using the applications. Once I get the notification, I should be able to display them on the top of my applcation.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same idea as @fastAsTortoise. A one-way notification channel (server to client) fits the exact purpose of Server-Sent-Events. I wouldn't introduce a new 3rd party library dependency for this because it's a straightforward task.

Look around for examples in your backend language. The client-side is really straightforward. In your root component's `ngOnInit` method, you can open the channel and subscribe to its messages

```
eventChannel = new EventSource('YOUR_SERVER_URL_HERE');

ngOnInit(){
    Observable.fromEvent(this.eventChannel, 'open').subscribe(
        () => console.log('channel is open')
    );
    Observable.fromEvent(this.eventChannel, 'message').subscribe(
        e => console.log('message received', e.data)
    );
}
```

Checkout [the interface for Server-Sent-Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events)

Comment: Thanks. But if I want to change it to a two way communication in the future, what would be the best choice.

Comment: @indra257 websocket will be the highest performing. You could also use Ajax polling (making a request every 90 seconds for example and seeing whether the server returns a new message) which is easier to implement but not as efficient.

Comment: I dont want to use Ajax polling, because these are emergency notifications which should be displayed immediately. So the best option is websockets? Is Signalr a best option ?

Comment: @indra257 I'm not familiar with Signalr. If you need immediate notification, I would use Server-Sent-Events or Websockets. The former is much simpler to implement and perfect for one-way comms (when all the client has to do is listen to notifications). The latter is significantly more complex to implement but perfect for two-way comms.

Comment: I have Java lang on server and i am also looking for similar functionality. What would be the best approach? I want to catch notification from server. I have chatbox where i want to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

SignalR would be able to work here.
This is what I would plan:

1. In your .net application have a single hub setup so it can broadcast events.
2. In your angular app include signalR.js and then
3. Create listening events and alerts based on what event gets broadcast from server.

This can be cross domain as well or if they are on same domain it will work out of the box. I tried this on a mobile app using phonegap and it worked perfectly and both android and iphone were able to perform actions when server sent an event to users or groups.

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends on whatever the server side language that you are currently using,

If you want to write your own chat framework you can start using **[`socket.io`](https://socket.io/)**

If you want to write with .net, you can use **[`signalR`](https://www.asp.net/signalr)** with dot net core

**[Google material](https://material.io/guidelines/)** is a design framework which is totally different from what you are looking for.  You can also look into some 3rd party libraries which you can implement in quick time such as **[`pusher`](https://pusher.com/)**

Comment: I am using Angular4 with cli. The backend is in .net.  I am not looking for a complete chat framework. I just need to display the emergency alerts and notifications on my application.

Comment: then save it in the database and retrive and show it

Comment: I may get the emergency/alert notification at any time, not only at the page load event,

Comment: then you need to implement as i mentioned above